# Polar Bar using Altair

Tags: python, altair

is it possible to make a polar chart using altair? I need to replay Florence Nightingale’s using altair, I didn't find any example talking about polar charts using altair.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, the current Altair release (version 4.1) does not support polar plots. Recent releases of Vega-Lite added support for this(see [vega-lite Arc examples](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/arc.html)), so future versions of Altair may eventually support this.